# Does the item damage indicator take the skills used into account?

Tags: diablo-iii

So if I got a weapon that gives me bonus poison or elemental damage and/or bonus skill damage to a skill which I use, is this taken into account in the added/substracted damage rating of the item?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I'm not certain.

Comment: not sure if this is a separate question or dupe http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158142/why-are-some-stats-on-items-marked-with-orange-diamond-and-primary-secondary-tit

Comment: The answer applies, but different question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No its not.  If you notice, those slots have an [orange diamond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158142/why-are-some-stats-on-items-marked-with-orange-diamond-and-primary-secondary-tit) on them meaning they aren't taken into account for comparisons.

However, those stats will now show up in your detailed character sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Bonus *skill/elemental* damage is not calculated into the shown DPS. All bonus *skill/elemental* damage have an orange indicator in front of it. And [this means](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158143/39891) they are not included in your shown DPS.

Comment: bonus element damage % do have orange on them fyi

Comment: Do they? I'll go doublecheck. I checked some random screenshot on google, I'll go check ingame now.

Comment: @Aperum they do, I checked before posting

Comment: @z' dammit google! You failed me. I checked ingame now (took a while to find an item with elemental damage on it) and you are indeed right.